# Simulate tab key press (Ember.js)

Tags: javascript, ember.js, keypress, ember-components

Good day!

I have a collection of textfields and they're arranged horizontally, What I want is to imitate Mircosoft excel's behaviour when I press the enter key it would automatically go down to the next row and focus on first input.

One approach I'm looking forward is to simulate tab press when I press the enter key.

For now I'm using this jquery approach:

```
function save() {
  let focusedElement = Ember.$(event.target);
  let nextForm = 5; //some integer value to get the next ember-id
  Ember.$("#ember"+ nextForm +"").select();
}
```

I want to make it more Ember way because right now it's anti component pattern.

Comment: There are many ember addons that make it easy to respond to keyboard events: https://www.emberobserver.com/categories/keyboard-events

Comment: Hi @Gaurav I already look at the link that you gave me but those ember add ons are just for catching keyboard shortcuts and fire a certain action and not for simulating keyboard press.

Comment: Why do you need to simulate keyboard press. Just change the action for the enter key and prevent default.